# Using Typeface on another Android Activity

Tags: android, typeface, android-typeface

I want to use Typeface on a TextView I have created on another android activity. I have used the typeface on the main activity and it works. When I follow the same procedure in another activity, the app crashes - it tells me the font cannot be found.

The New Activity Screen (this launches from a button click):

```
public class RegisterUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView heading, description;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);

    Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Hanken-Light.ttf");
    heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerTitleHeading);
    description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
    heading.setTypeface(myFont);
    description.setTypeface(myFont);


}
```

A bit of the main activity (this code works):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Snipped

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainHeading);

    Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Hanken-Light.ttf");
    mainHeading.setTypeface(myFont);
    myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    myView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
```

When trying to use assets from another activity, is there something else I must do??

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: If you do not want to change `typeface` dynamically then you can make a custom `textview` class and use that class in your layout.

Comment: Nothing in your code looks obviously out of place. You could try adding getApplicationContext().getAssets() instead of just getAssests() This should not be necessary though but may help

Answer (score 0):

Do like that :- 
Create Typefce above onCreate Method in RegisterUserActivity.

```
private TextView heading, description;
public static Typeface myFont;
```

Inside onCreate Method:

```
  myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Hanken-Light.ttf");

heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerTitleHeading);
description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
heading.setTypeface(myFont);
description.setTypeface(myFont)
```

In MainActivity  use like this

```
 mainHeading.setTypeface(RegisterUserActivity.myFont);
```

Happy coding and Happy To Help.

Comment: `mainHeading.setTypeface(RegisterUserActivity.myFont);` isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use another way for set custom font.
Follow below Steps.

1.put your font file in your asset folder.

2.create one class file name with same your font name for identification. See below.

```
 package com.bhadresh.CustomeView;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class SF_ui_display_lightTextView extends TextView {
        public SF_ui_display_lightTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();
        }

        public SF_ui_display_lightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
        }

        public SF_ui_display_lightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            init();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public SF_ui_display_lightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
            init();
        }
        private void init() {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "SF_ui_display_light.otf");//hear set your font name with extension which stored in your asset folder 
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
```

3. and after that you declare this class in your layout same as TextView like below.

Comment: copied code from somewhere which is saying `Created by tristate on 22/4/15.` at top

Comment: its not copied its developed by me for my company.but i have declared tag for copy on another location.